# How does a Wiener process with linear drift evolve?

Tags: normal-distribution, stochastic-processes, gaussian-process

A Wiener process with variance $v$ and zero drift starting at $x$ after time $t$ is normally distributed with mean $x$ and variance $vt$.

What happens with the increments when there is a linear drift $d=-kx$, where k is a positive constant?  This means that the process is drawn towards zero the farther away it is from zero.

My guess is that the distribution is still normal, maybe with mean $xe^{-kt}$ and variance $\frac{v}{k}(1-e^{-kt})$.  I have no idea how to show this though.  I tried to imagine the equilibrium of forces on a particle at position $x$, but I couldn't figure out how to compare the force of the linear drift with the force of the diffusion.

Comment: [Further vs. farther.  Is mathematical distance metaphorical or concrete?](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/further-versus-farther)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process described should follow, $dX_t=-KX_tdt+\sigma dW_t$.
Using $e^{Kt} (say\; v=\sigma^2)$ as the integrating factor we get,
$d(e^{Kt}X_t)=Ke^{Kt}X_tdt+e^{Kt}dX_t=Ke^{Kt}X_tdt-Ke^{Kt}X_tdt+\sigma e^{Kt}dW_t=\sigma e^{Kt}dW_t$
Upon integrating from $0$ to $t$, we get,
$X_t=X_0e^{-Kt}+\sigma\int_{0}^{t}e^{-K(t-s)}dW_s $

Now the integral we see above is an Ito Integral, hence,
$\int_{0}^{t}e^{-K(t-s)}dW_s\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\,\int_{0}^{t}e^{-2K(t-s)}ds)\,$
i.e. $\int_{0}^{t}e^{-K(t-s)}dW_s\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\,\frac{1}{2K}(1-e^{-2Kt}))\,$
i.e. $\sigma\int_{0}^{t}e^{-K(t-s)}dW_s\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\,\frac{\sigma^2}{2K}(1-e^{-2Kt}))\,$
i.e. $(X_0e^{-Kt}+\sigma\int_{0}^{t}e^{-K(t-s)}dW_s)\sim \mathcal{N}(X_0e^{-Kt},\,\frac{\sigma^2}{2K}(1-e^{-2Kt}))\,$
i.e. $X_t\sim \mathcal{N}(X_0e^{-Kt},\,\frac{\sigma^2}{2K}(1-e^{2Kt}))\,$

Note that since K>0, drift acts opposite to current value of the process. This causes $X_t$ to mean revert.

This process is popularly called the [Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process), used to model interest rates. You can look that up for further reading.

Comment: Thank you for the derivation and the name.   This answer goes above and beyond what I needed.  Warm welcome to stats.stackexchange!